# Can't do implode method to delimite number range

Tags: php

I have a range of number, say that it from 1 to 10.

```
  //$front_id = 1; 
  //$until_id = 10; 

  foreach (range($front_id, $until_id) as $number)
      {
          print_r($number)
          //12345678910
      }
```

It print a range of number between two variables as expected.

However, in the print result is it combine all number without any delimiter.

So, I tried to add a delimiter of comma here:

```
      $numbers = implode(',', $number);
```

But it doesn't work.

> Message:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: `$number` is only that - a number and not an array. `print implode(',', range(..));` however should work as expected

Comment: implode() Function means Join array elements with a string and number is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `$number` in array. Right now $number is not an array. That why you cannot implode. Define array first. Then inside `foreach()` you can store every `$number` in `$numbers` array.

```
$front_id = 1; 
$until_id = 10;
$numbers = array();
foreach (range($front_id, $until_id) as $number)
{
  $numbers[] = $number;
}
echo implode(',',$numbers);
```